# ASP.NET Identity subdomain path

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to read a Forms Authentication cookie in my MVC5 app (sub2) (from a subdomain (sub1)). I have the following in my Web.Config

```
<machineKey decryption="AES" validation="SHA1" validationKey="010D62DCblah blah" decryptionKey="blah blah" />
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="http://sub1.domain.us.com/Authentication/Login?site=billing" timeout="2880" name=".COOKIE" protection="All" />
</authentication>
<httpCookies domain=".domain.us.com" httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="false" />
```

Startup.Auth.cs

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    LoginPath = new PathString("/Authentication/Login"),
    CookieDomain = ".domain.us.com",

});
```

**So my MVC5 site is:**

sub2.domain.us.com

**and Authentication site is:** sub1.domain.us.com

How do I make it go to sub1.domain.us.com in order to perform a log in??

Is this even possible? am I on the right track?
Right now it takes me to sub2.domain.us.com/Authentication/Login instead of sub1.domain.us.com/Authentication/Login
OR How do I make Startup.Auth.cs use The info in web.config loginUrl?

thanks

Comment: When exactly do you want it to go to `sub1.domain.us.com`?

Comment: that is where the website with the login stuff exists. I would log in and generate a cookie there

Comment: Ok, so you want to users to be able to login on `sub1.domain.us.com` but be logged in for `sub2.domain.us.com` and you also want any login requests or redirects to the login page to be directed to `sub1.domain.us.com`?

Comment: This is what I want. Whenever [Authorize] attribute exists - it should redirect users to sub1, once valid login and passwd provided sub1 would log on the user, and create a cookie, then redirect user back to sub2

Comment: Create a custom `AuthorizeAttribute` attribute with the result to redirect to your subdomain.

Comment: that does not work. it still redirects in the domain specified in Startup.auth.cs

Comment: Your authentication site needs to be setup to issue access tokens to your MVC5 site. Then you need to use `app.UseExternalSignInCookie(...)` instead, treating your authentication site as a third party provider. Forms auth isn't going to work because it's incompatible with identity.